# C++ Representing Objects in a YAML file

Tags: java, c++, spring-boot, yaml, metaprogramming

I used to work with the Java framework spring boot which has this neat functionality where
you can have an yaml file like this:

```
config:
  example_int: 17
```

And a java class like this:

```
public class Config {
  int example_int;
  config(example_int) {
    this.example_int = example_int;
  }
}
```

The framework would then (if I remember correctly) inject into the runtime
an instance of class `Config` with `example_int` data member initialized to 17.

I'm looking to implement a similar functionality in C++
i.e. parse a yaml file and then construct a c++ object based on the files contents.

While (I think) Spring uses runtime injection I think I could do this via meta programming to
reduce complexity.
TLDR:

1. Parse yaml with C++
2. Based on yaml configs inject an object into the runtime, or generate code via
   metaprogramming, which has the characteristics defined in the yaml file.